# Elementor and WPGlobus compatibility issues

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I actually have a problem. I’m using the plugin „WPGlobus“ together with the page builder “Elementor“.. both with the newest version. In general it works... but there are two compatibility issues:

1. Saving templates from pages or blocks does not work if WPGlobus is activated. The saved page or block is always empty...
2. If I create and finish a page in the primary language and want to translate it into another language, I get a empty page and need to create it again from beginning instead of just replace the text strings.

Are this knowing issues? Maybe there exist a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use WPGlobus as well since my customer wants to use WooCommerce and have multiple languages that require different currencies. Your first problem is something I haven't encountered yet but I have been dealing with your second problem.

Something I did in order to still use it (even though it could be better) is to save the original page as a page template. Then when you're editing the page for another language, you can just import the page template and edit it to your heart's content.

The problem I'm facing right now has to do with the header and footer, I can't seem to change these for the different languages... I've contacted WPGlobus and I'm waiting for their response.